# Call Google Apps Script API with GmailApp function from Postman [without using AuthO2]

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I am trying to access the **Google Apps Script Gmail service** with **Postman**.
Here is my Google Apps Script Code, with a straightforward sendMail function:

```
function sendMail() {
  GmailApp.sendEmail('email@gmail.com','from inTracck','Test for new API source')
}
```

As you may see, it's a code to send a simple email.
After deploying my project in Google Apps Script, I've got a Web App address to use on my postman:

```
Web App Address:
https://script.google.com/macros/s/.../exec
```

I put it all on my Postman, here is how I use it:
[image: Google Apps Script API in Postman]

Now, the issue is that when I **send** the **API**, it doesn't work.
I know that I might have to fill out the body section, but since I'm not very technical, I didn't know how to fill that to make the API works and send an email from my Postman.

Comment: With what configuration did you publish the web app?

Comment: @TheMaster Actually I haven't put any codes in the 'body', as I didn't know about the relevant ones. Since the Google Apps Script worked with that functions, I thought it could be work on the Postman with just the API link.

Comment: I'm asking about publishing configuration.

Comment: @TheMaster I haven't published it yet, cause first I need to see the 'send' button works in the Postman and the email is sent

Comment: No.. the web app publishing configuration: Execute as "?": Who has access:"?". [Edit] that information into the question.

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web?hl=en#permissions

Comment: @TheMaster oh, I see. It is executed as anyone. You can find the image down below:
[link]https://i.ibb.co/4N9tFBH/ggg.png

Comment: Without, oauth, you should set to execute as "me" and access:"anyone"

Comment: @TheMaster I've set the setting as below, but still, the code does not execute directly from the Postman: https://i.ibb.co/2YGBf0d/800.png

Comment: Is there a `doGet()` in your script? You need a script to return something. Read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web fully

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks, I read the post. So, the code should be sth like that?
-------
` function sendMail() {
  GmailApp.sendEmail('test@gmail.com','from ...','Test for new API source')
}

function doGet(sendEmail) {
  var params = JSON.stringify(sendEmail);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(params);
}`

Comment: See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [`doGet()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) function to return data:

```
function doGet(){
  sendMail();// call send email function
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('Email Sent!')
}
```

You should publish it with these configurations:

- Execute as "Me"
- Access:"Anyone"

Note: Republishing changes the URL. Make sure to use the newly published URL in Postman.

Comment: Thank you very much @TheMaster . It really helpful and now I can execute my Google Apps Script code from the Postman.